# How to maintain order of levels after factorizing column in R

Tags: r, sorting, categorical-data

I have a permutation of different electrodes (25x25=625) from frontal to parietal.

```
> head(grph_test)
  Elec1 Elec2
1   Fp1   Fp1
2   Fp1   Fp2
3   Fp1    F7
4   Fp1    F3
5   Fp1    Fz
6   Fp1    F4
```

The thing is I want to factorize the columns but it changes the level order to alphabetical, which is not useful for my purpose.

```
> test$Elec1 <- factor(test$Elec1, ordered = is.ordered(test$Elec1))
> levels(grph_test$Elec1)
 [1] "C3"  "C4"  "CP1" "CP2" "CP5" "CP6" "Cz"  "F3"  "F4"  "F7"  "F8"  "FC1" "FC2" "FC5" "FC6" "Fp1" "Fp2" "Fz"  "Oz"  "P3"  "P4"  "P7"  "P8" 
[24] "POz" "Pz"
```

While my expectation was they would end up in the same order as the original column, which follows something like the following list:

```
"Fp1","Fp2","F7","F3","Fz","F4","F8","FC5","FC1","FC2","FC6","C3","Cz","C4","CP5","CP1","CP2","CP6","P7","P3","Pz","P4","P8","POz","Oz"
```

I thought, according to the documentation, `ordered = is.ordered(test$Elec1)` argument would be capable of mantaining the original order, but as you can see it does not.

Any idea why? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `unique` in the `levels` argument of `factor` as `unique` returns the unique values from the first occurrence of that element, thus it maintains the same order of occurrence as in the original data

```
test$Elec1 <- factor(test$Elec1, levels = unique(test$Elec1))
```

---

NOTE: `is.ordered` returns a logical output

Comment: Thank you @akrun, it did not occur to me to use unique. It did the trick!